# Error al desplegar Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea

Intento desplegar la aplicación ejemplo de **Google App Engine** dentro de mi propio proyecto que cree en la consola de desarrollado de Google, ya agregue el ID del proyecto y en teoría debería funcionar.

Pero la consola para visualizar el Despliegue en IntellijIDEA arroja esta información.

> Beginning interaction for module default...
>
> Password for mi.correo@google.com: 
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad authentication response: 404 Not Found
>   Unable to update app: Bad authentication response: 404 Not Found
>   Please see the logs [/tmp/appcfg6920280188625618051.log] for further
>   information. Failed to deploy 'helloworld:war exploded': Process
>   terminated with exit code 1

Ya revise la documentacion y prácticamente es lo único que debo de cambiar para que funcione sin problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dos cosas a considerar:

1. La version de app engine que usas en tu proyecto, checa que sea la mas reciente.
2. En la configuración de tu profile (maven por ejemplo), checa que tengas habilitada la autenticacion por medio de **OAuth**, es mas sencillo y solo tienes que autenticarte una vez para poder realizar varios deployments, en caso contrario tienes que generar un token por cada vez que quieras hacer publish.

Comment: El segundo punto soluciono mi problema.